# How to manipulate DOM using Svelte framework

Tags: dom, svelte

I'm pretty much new to Svelte framework. Recently I'm playing around with Svelte but confused how I would manipulate the DOM like in jQuery using Svelte.

I'm trying to show/hide an `<li>` on button click.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Svelte, and other state-driven UI frameworks, you very rarely manipulate the DOM. Instead, you essentially tell the framework what the DOM should look like *for some given data*, and let it figure out all the details.

So to show or hide elements in response to a button click, you'd do something like this ([REPL link](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.49.1&gist=6185186ce918a8bb38455a7ea273b0c5)):

```
<button on:click='set({ visible: !visible })'>toggle visibility</button>

{{#if visible}}
  <p>hello!</p>
{{/if}}
```

Or, if you want to keep the element in the DOM but make it hidden ([REPL link](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.49.1&gist=b5d2da4838f53949f3f0cc1aa9a82c45)):

```
<button on:click='set({ visible: !visible })'>toggle visibility</button>

<p hidden='{{!visible}}'>hello!</p>
```

This is **much better** than manually manipulating the DOM, because you can change all the details — what kind of element it is and therefore what jQuery selector you'd use to target it, whether there are other things that also need to change based on `visible`, etc — without having to rewrite all your code.